# A label for multiple equations

Tags: math-mode

The following code gives two examples:
The former gives only one label for two equations with a redundant notation "{ ", but the later gives three labels (It should be two?).

Is it possible to give only one label for multiple equations without the notation "{"?

```
\begin{eqnarray}
  \begin{cases}
A &\sim a,\\
B &\sim b,\\
  \end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{align}\label{General}
A &\sim a,\\
B &\sim b,\\
\end{align}
```

[image]

My desired output is the following;
[image]

Comment: I've changed the tag to math-mode; your example is using latex, so it's not "tex-core".  Both of the answers use structures defined by `amsmath`.  It could be instructive for you to read the `amsmath` users guide.  If you're using a TeX Live installation, this can be accessed by typing `texdoc amsmath` at a command line prompt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using `split` environment, and the tags are:

```
\begin{equation}\label{General}
\begin{split}
A &\sim a,\\
B &\sim b,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Thank you for  quick reply, it is quite new for me, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an aligned environment nested within your equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        A &\sim a,\\
        B &\sim b,
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, it helps me a lot.

Comment: There's no need for the final ``\\`` in a stack.